# Why does TextField keep resetting to Original Value while typing in Flutter?

Tags: forms, flutter, uitextfield

I made a TextField in Flutter with a placeholder value so that users can edit the value. However when I try to edit the field, every millisecond (I don't even get time to type more than 3 characters) the field keeps resetting back to the original value. How do I fix this?

Here's what the Controller/Text field look like, all inside a Stateful Widget's build() function:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    balance = globals.user.balance;
    String balancePretty = Utils.getMoneyPretty(balance);

    TextEditingController balanceController = TextEditingController(text: balancePretty)

    TextField balanceField = TextField(
      cursorColor: Colors.green,
      controller: balanceController,
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.green),
      onSubmitted: (text) {
        print("First text field: $text");
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
            child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                balanceField,
            ])));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Reason : because you put `TextEditingController balanceController` in `build` 
Solution : You can init placeholder value in `initState`

code snippet

```
TextEditingController balanceController;

@override
void initState() {
    //balance = globals.user.balance;
    String balancePretty = "123"; //Utils.getMoneyPretty(balance);
    balanceController = TextEditingController(text: balancePretty);
    super.initState();
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController balanceController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //balance = globals.user.balance;
    String balancePretty = "123"; //Utils.getMoneyPretty(balance);
    balanceController = TextEditingController(text: balancePretty);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextField balanceField = TextField(
      cursorColor: Colors.green,
      controller: balanceController,
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.green),
      onSubmitted: (text) {
        print("First text field: $text");
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
          balanceField,
        ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, super helfpful.

Answer (score 3):

Your textEditing controller is inside your build method, so when the widget rebuilds (i.e. when you start typing) it resets the value back to the initial value you provided it.

So make it a global variable and it should be fine (like this:)

```
 TextEditingController balanceController = TextEditingController(text:balancePretty)
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  balance = globals.user.balance;
  String balancePretty = Utils.getMoneyPretty(balance);
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a placeholder (hint) you need to use hintText property of the TextField. What you are doing is passing a text to the controller, not setting the placeholder/hint.